# Why commitNow does not set fragment to null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have tried to use `commitNow` for ensuring that fragment transactions are synchronous. However, after my testing, I found that for some reason `commitNow` does not remove fragments immediately.

I have added a Handler with postDelayed 100 milliseconds and the fragment was still not null. After that, I changed `postDelayed` to 1000 milliseconds and finally, the fragment was null.

How can I ensure **that the fragment is null immediately** after I call `commitNow`? I tried to add `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()`, but no help.

If it is impossible to make fragment null immediately, how can I check if that fragment is no longer in the stack, before adding the same fragment?

**UPDATE**
I found that if I removed `setCustomAnimations`, then transactions are indeed occurring immediately. **How can I observe when `setCustomAnimations` have finished?**

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(DEMO_FRAGMENT)
    if (fragment != null) {
        Log.d("test", "DEMO_FRAGMENT is not null")
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.custom_fade_in, R.anim.custom_fade_out)
                    .remove(fragment).commitNow()
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
            Log.d("test", "is fragment null:${supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(DEMO_FRAGMENT) == null}")
            Handler().postDelayed({
                Log.d("test", "is fragment null:${supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(DEMO_FRAGMENT) == null}")
            }, 1000)
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use `popBackStackImmediate()`. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#popbackstackimmediate)